# MIPS bne beq Computer Organization and Design

Tags: if-statement, assembly, conditional-statements, mips, micro-optimization

So, I'll quote my textbook(Computer Organization and Design) and then I'll ask my question:

> ###### Compiling if-then-else into Conditional branches
>
> In the following code segment, `f, g, j, i` and `j` are variables. If the five variables `f` through `j` correspond to the five registers `$s0` through `$s4`, what is the compiled MIPS code for this C if statement?
>
> ```
> if (i == j) f = g + h; else f = g - h;
> ```
>
> Figure 2.9 is a flowchart of what the MIPS code should do. The first expression compares for equality, so it would seem that we would want the branch if registers are equal instruction (beq). **In general, the code will be more efficient if we test for the opposite condition to branch over the code that performs the subsequent then part of the if (the label Else is defined below) and so we use the branch if registers are not equal instruction (bne):**
>
> ```
> bne $s3, $s4, Else # go to Else if i ≠ j
> ```

I've searched for a while but I couldn't find why `bne` would be more efficient than `beq`.
(I did however find that bne is sometimes recommended because it makes the code easier to understand, as the statements to be executed when the condition holds are right below the bne statement.)

So, if it would not be more efficient in general, it still could be more efficient in this particular exercise. I've thought about that, and I assumed that a branch instruction costs more time if taken, and therefore we'd want to minimize the amount of jumps (taken branches) needed. This means that, when we expect the condition to hold, we should use `bne`, and when we expect the condition to fail, we should use `beq`.

Now if we test whether `$s3` equals `$s4`, when we have no information whatsoever about the content of those registers it's not reasonable to assume that they're likely to be equal.  On the contrary, it's more likely that they're not equal, which should favour using `beq` instead of `bne`.

So, to sum up: textbook says `bne` is more efficient than `beq`, whether it's in general or just in this example is not clear, but in either case I don't understand why.

Comment: I don't see a question there, but that's a lot of assumptions without much to back them up...

Comment: I think it would be rare for any conditional branch to be more "efficient" than another (at least for general-purpose registers and flags - some of the system/control/special-purpose registers/flags might have a performance penalty associated). Probably the reason `bne` is seen to be "more efficient" is a psychological one where coders tend to write code of the form `if (most_likely_condition) something(); else something_else();`. That, along with branchless code being more cache-friendly, might tend to make "the opposite condition" "more efficient".

Comment: To make it clear (I'll edit my post in a min): The textbook literally said that bne would be more efficient, my question is why. I don't assume anything to prove them wrong, I just came up with a couple of theories why bne and beq could have different efficiency, but each of these theories applied to this example result in bne NOT being more efficient.

Comment: I am also reading this textbook recently. It's really helping me out with the idea of computer architecture.
<br>
<br>
I have a hypothesis, that the difference of efficiency is from **direct comparison of machine code** of `bne` and `beq`.
<br>
<br>
Consider that two instructions are comparing two register. The operation of `beq` must go through every bit to give an answer and store it to the register of destination. On the other hand, `bne` might counter difference in first few.
<br>
<br>
**I don't have any solid evidence for the hypothesis**. I'm really glad if someone can back this up or op

Answer (score 2):

The efficiency is not from a direct comparison of the machine code for a bne versus beq.  The text describes optimizing the over all performance by coding to shorten the most common code path.

<strike>If you assume the values are more likely to be unequal then only one instruction needs be processed when using bne, if you use beq you must perform an additional jump on failure.</strike>

The shortest path is to drop through the compare, to fail it and not jump.

from http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~setia/cs365-S02/class3.pdf:

**Uncommon Case for branches**

beq $18, $19, L1

- else handling
- jmp

replaced by

bne $18, $19, L2

- success handling
- end

L2:

**Make the common case fast -
one instruction for most branches**

Re-reading your question, I think the crux is this assumption:

> "Now if we test whether $s3 equals $s4, when we have no information
>   whatsoever about the content of those registers, it's not reasonable
>   to assume that they're likely to be equal; on the contrary, it's more
>   likely that they're not equal, which should result in using beq
>   instead of bne."

This seems to be the confusion, we need to find some evidence or reason to determine which possibility is more likely, registers equal or unequal.

In this case we are examining an if-then-else. I make the assertion that we expect the if-test to pass, this is the psychology described by twalberg. The registers are unlikely to contain random values as they contain data that the programer is expecting - the result of previous operations.

Comment: Edit: I can't work with this thing, no idea how to go to a new line. I'm fairly certain I'm following your logic (since make the common case fast is what I tried to do, just forgot to explain it like that), but I'm not sure I totally get it. I'll quote you: 
"If you assume the values are more likely to be unequal then only one instruction needs be processed when using bne, if you use beq you must perform an additional jump on failure." Isn't it exactly the opposite? beq will jump if they're equal, so if you don't expect them to be equal, you should use bne I'd think?

Comment: I had to think about it a bit, the idea is that if you expect the values to not be equal then use bne as only one instruction will be followed. If you expect them to be equal then use beq. When either comparison fails you have an additional instruction  - a jump. Write your code so the "failure" jump is used as infrequently as possible.

Comment: Do not let me confuse you, or myself. The cost of performing a comparison with bne or beq are going to be the same, the efficiency will come from minimizing the code path

Comment: Yes but I'm completely confused with the following: I'd say that if you expect values to be equal you'd use bne (since bne means jumping on not equal, which is less frequently if you expect equal), but you say that if I expect them to be equal I should use beq, and I'm confused.

Comment: yeah, I agree it is confusing. As I remember it the goal was to jump least often. As noted by twalberg above we tend to test for success, passing the test means we jump. I want the code to fall through after the compare - to stay local. Test for failure so the code falls through on the value we want to work with, branch on the unexpected, on failure.

Comment: I can see you edited your post. If I'm correct you now agree with me that a test that fails will not jump. Therefore, like you say, we should test the uncommon case. Now seeing the code in my example, is there any way the book can be correct with saying bne is more efficient (in this example), or is it a mistake? I'm not saying beq is per se more efficient, but I don't see any way how bne could be. (By the way thank you a lot for responding so much!)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has something to do with simplifying the compiler. In the case that you have an equality assertion, you would want to skip over the code to execute if the condition is not met. I would assume that this decision was made to use the exact same procedure in the case where you do have an else condition and not. Here's what I think. By all means, if my reasoning is wrong, please tell me! :)

Starting with the given pseudocode from OP:

```
if (i == j) {
  f = g + h;
}
else {
  f = g - h;
}
```

Would translate to:

```
      bne  $s3, $s4, Else
      add  $s0, $s1, $s2
      j    Exit
Else: sub  $s0, $s1, $s2
Exit: ...
```

If you changed the C code to just perform the addition if `i == j`:

```
if (i == j) {
  f = g + h;
}
```

The compiler would come up with something like this:

```
      bne  $s3, $s4, Exit
      add  $s0, $s1, $s2
Exit: ...
```

Now, let's think about what the compiled code would look like if we tested the assertion using `beq` instead. I'm guessing it would look somewhat like this:

```
      beq  $s3, $s4, Equal
      j    Exit
Equal:
      add  $s0, $s1, $s2
Exit: ...
```

Which seems a lot less efficient than testing with `bne`.

EDIT
There's also the fact that checking for inequality is faster for a CPU than checking for equality.

If you try to compare 2 32 bit numbers for equality, the CPU has to compare every single bit of that 32 bit number to make sure they are equal. If testing for non-equality, if the first bits of the 2 numbers are different, the CPU doesn't have to bother with testing any of the other bits to assert the inequality.

Comment: Yes, that braindead beq-over-a-`j` model might be what they had in mind as the alternative, and a naive / simplistic assumption they were going to lay out the asm with `if` and `else` blocks in the same order as the C source.  (Which is of course not necessary; you can put the if or the else block after the end of the function so the fast path doesn't even have to jump over it.  (e.g. `beq i,j, if_body`, and there some instructions with a `j done`).  Profile-guided optimization by real compilers will do this when it has profiling info to show that one side runs much more often than the other.)

Comment: I feel like I'm coming so late to the party, but I'm just now getting into this. Thanks for your explanation, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this is that simple [branch predictors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) usually assume that forward branches are not taken and that backwards branches are taken. This assumption gives better performance for simple loops.